# Making a simple project hangman

Tags: python, list

I run the code it works fine to the point it decrements the `counter` for the first time but after that the value of `counter` remain the same.

Can someone point what could be the cause of this? I looked at the code more than 10 times. Tried some different approaches, still nothing.

Code:

```
import random
import time

# GLOBAL VARIABLES
word_bank = ["january", "border", "image", "film", "promise", "kids", "lungs", "doll", "rhyme", "damage", "plants"]
guessed = []
word = random.choice(word_bank)
display = '_' * len(word)
counter = len(word)
secret_word = word
run = True


def welcome():
    print('\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tHello welcome to HangMan Game')
    time.sleep(1)
    print("The game is about to start")
    print(f" Secret Word : {display}\n")
    print('Start Guessing \n')
    time.sleep(1)


def guessing(counter=counter):
    print(secret_word)
    guess = input('Enter your guess : ')
    if guess in secret_word:
        print(guess)
        print('You Guessed it Right!')
        guessed.append(guess)
    elif guess not in secret_word:
        print('You Guessed Wrong!')
        counter -= 1
        print(f'You Remaining guesses are {counter}')
        return counter
    for j in guessed:
        if j[:] == secret_word and counter > 0:
            print('You Won!')
        elif counter == 0:
            print('Your out of moves. You Lost!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    welcome()
    while run:
        guessing()
```

Comment: share the code and explain the problem

Comment: @balderman In guessing method when the user enters the wrong guess. It should say you guessed wrong and the counter should decrement which works fine for the very first time but after that the counter value remains the same, no matter how many times i enter a wrong guess.

Comment: @Abdullah Also, I'll note that once this code **works as expected**, you can post the **complete code** on [codereview.se] to get general suggestions on how to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`counter=counter` doesn't mean that the value of `counter` will be automatically maintained. It means that if you don't pass an argument to `guessing`, it will use the *original* value of `counter` that you set at the top.

Since you're returning `counter` anyways, just use the return value:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    welcome()
    current_counter = counter
    while run:
        # Reassign the new counter value, then use it the next time
        current_counter = guessing(current_counter)
```

Note though, this will only work if `guessing` *always* returns a `counter` value. Currently though, some of your branches don't (like everything in `for j in guessed:`). Failing to return a `counter` value will lead to an error similar to:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'NoneType' and 'int'